# How to improve jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the syntax below. I was wondering if this part: `$($(this).parent().siblings('div')[0])` could be writen more elegantly by accessing a jQuery object directly without the need to use `$();` again.

I used `.parent().siblings` and didn't use the class of `div` because I want to reuse the code somewhere where the classes are different.

```
$('textarea').click(function(){
     $($(this).parent().siblings('div')[0]).html('<span>140</span>');
     $($(this).parent().siblings('div')[1]).html('<span>Reply</span>');
});

<div class="post_area2">
    <div class="wrap_area2 left">
        <textarea></textarea> 
    </div>
    <div class="word_c left"></div>
    <div class="submit left"></div>   
</div>
```

Comment: @MohammadAdil - Why? The question is strictly about the jQuery notation.

Comment: @RichardJPLeGuen So that someone can suggest better option's..

Comment: The OP wasn't asking for improvements to their HTML structure: only for a way to consolidate their jQuery code. We should focus on what they asked.

Comment: Having the HTML is a useful if you want to create a jsfiddle, otherwise you have to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('textarea').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().next().html('<span>140</span>')
      .next().html('<span>Reply</span>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rVfJ4/

Comment: this one is realy a elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `.eq()` method.

```
$('textarea').click(function(){
     $(this).parent().siblings('div')
                     .eq(0).html('<span>140</span>').end()
                     .eq(1).html('<span>Reply</span>');
});
```

Comment: @undefined pls add some more explanation.. want to know what end() does in this example

Answer (score 2):

I agree with sweetamylase's answer.
That code should work. Because it is using native javascript, I think it is good for performance.

Or use class name for determinate div:

```
$('textarea').click(function(){
    var parentDiv = $(this).parents('div.post_area2'); // avoid to use $(this) multi time in this function
    parentDiv.find('div.word_c').html('<span>140</span>');
    parentDiv.find('div.submit').html('<span>Reply</span>');
});
```

That will work exactly even you add new another div.

Don't use 'eq()' if you have another solution.

I'm sorry, I'm not enough reputation for voting.

Comment: at somethings it's more important the elegance of the code than performance because that piece of logic will not have a impact very big so it's more important have a good code that is maintainable

Answer (score 1):

I would re-write it as such:

```
$('textarea').click(function(){
     var divContainer = $(this).parent().siblings('div');
     divContainer[0].innerHTML = '<span>140</span>';
     divContainer[1].innerHTML = '<span>Reply</span>';
});
```

You can use native attribute `innerHTML` to set the contents of the DOM element, it is equivalent to using `.html()` minus the requirement of invoking the jQuery object.

Also, it depends if your coding style likes to do *chaining* because that's really easily done with jQuery, but can be difficult to read when the line becomes long.

Comment: This will fail, as divContainer[0] is a simple div not a jQuery object.

Comment: You could use `divContainer.eq(0)` though.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to use the `$.html()` since it's the pretty much the same as using `innerHTML` except you do not need to invoke the jQuery object which would be a more expensive operation.

Comment: the array returned by .siblings() has dom elements and not jquery objects

Comment: You are right @sweetamylase, but you have written .html() before you edited your answer :) Now it is ok.

Comment: Using `html()` allows jquery to do cleanups if jquery added data to the child nodes of this element. Otherwise you could get memory leaks.

Comment: This answer is now OK. Don't downvote it. I upvoted it, for balancing the universe. @BogdanVolosincu that is not actually true. .siblings() return a jQuery object, which works similarly to an array of DOM elements.

Comment: @SoonDead If you're going to use jQuery to add/remove elements, you should **always** use it. If you look at the jQuery source code, which I don't expect you to do, jQuery does a lot of cleanup (for internal things, like event handlers and data) when you call methods like `.remove()`, `.empty()`, `.html()`, `.replaceWith()`, etc. So if you decide not to use jQuery to manipulate the DOM, the cleanup won't necessarily happen.

Comment: @SoonDead i just can tell you where you can find this in source and check yourself. in the `1.9.x` look for the function `html: function( value )`  there you have the comment `// Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks`  and the call `jQuery.cleanData` if you look in the definition of `cleanData` you will see that events are cleanup and that all data that is set with `.data(...)` is released which otherwise will stay in memory until page is left.

Comment: @t.niese I have checked the source a little after I asked the question above and just came back to thank for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like this

```
$('textarea').click(function () {
    var parentSiblings = $(this).parent().siblings('div');

    $(parentSiblings[0]).html('<span>140</span>');
    $(parentSiblings[1]).html('<span>Reply</span>');
});
```

Or

```
$('textarea').click(function () {
    var parentSiblings = $($(this).parent().siblings('div'));

    parentSiblings.eq(0).html('<span>140</span>');
    parentSiblings.eq(1).html('<span>Reply</span>');
});
```

Others may see using vanilla javascript more elegant.

```
function empty(element) {
    "use strict";

    while (element.hasChildNodes()) {
        element.removeChild(element.lastChild);
    }
}

function addEvent(nodeList, type, callBack) {
    "use strict";

    var length = nodeList.length,
        i = 0;

    while (i < length) {
        nodeList[i].addEventListener(type, callBack, false);
        i += 1;
    }
}

addEvent(document.getElementsByTagName("textarea"), "click", function (evt) {
    "use strict";

    var divContainer = evt.target.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div"),
        span;

    empty(divContainer[1]);
    span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = "140";
    divContainer[1].appendChild(span);

    empty(divContainer[2]);
    span = document.createElement("span");
    span.textContent = "Reply";
    divContainer[2].appendChild(span);
});
```

These and others are available on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/ukueM/)

I guess it depends on how exactly you define more elegant. Sometimes readability is more important, perhaps not including ant 3rd party libraries and using vanilla javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You should give the other `div`s extra classes to represent what they mean.

```
$('textarea').click(function(){
     $(this).parents('form').children('.hide-until-using-form').show();
});
```

This creates a highly reusable function that doesn't depend on how many siblings are involved, what the text of the button is (Post? Edit?), etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is infinite ways to do it,

You can think a bit out of the box, i'm not sure that the latest version of jquery optimize the access to elements, if i'm wrong feel free to make me sorry on it.

But here are a few ways to do it:

```
var parentSelector = $(this).parent().parent();
var parentSelector = $(this).parents('#uniqueId');

var currentId = this.id;
var childrenSelector = parentSelector.children('div[id!="' + currentId + '"'];

var one = $(childrenSelector.get(0));
var two = $(childrenSelector.get(1));
```

A simple way to optimize the access to elements is to wrap/create new function that save reference to DOM elements, there is some issues that need to be consider but you can make a nice dom-cache library.